# Change the mouse cursor on mouse over to anchor-like style

Tags: javascript, mouse

If I hover the mouse over a `div` the mouse cursor will be changed to the cursor like that in HTML anchor.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

Assuming your `div` has an `id="myDiv"`, add the following to your CSS. The `cursor: pointer` specifies that the cursor should be the same hand icon that is use for anchors (hyperlinks):

**CSS to Add**

```
#myDiv
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can simply add the cursor style to your `div`'s HTML like this:

```
<div style="cursor: pointer">

</div>
```

**EDIT:**

If you are determined to use jQuery for this, then add the following line to your `$(document).ready()` or body `onload`:  (replace `myClass` with whatever class all of your `div`s share)

```
$('.myClass').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: I want to do this with jquery not css

Comment: @guru: There is no need for scripting. All you need to do is add `style="cursor: pointer"` to your `div`'s HTML. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: There are five division with same class, i can't add to all this "style="cursor: pointer"

Comment: @guru, if all of the div's have the same class, then you can actually add "cursor: pointer" to the CSS rule for that class in your page's CSS file

Comment: if the problem is one of targeting, then as Justin already asked, and as everyone always has to ask, POST THE CODE so we can help you attach it

Comment: @guru: See my **EDIT:** in my answer. I show you how to do what you want using only jQuery; you don't have to modify your CSS file.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to do this in jQuery instead of CSS, you basically follow the same process.

Assuming you have some `<div id="target"></div>`, you can use the following code:

```
$("#target").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}, function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','auto');
});
```

and that should do it.

Comment: This is superfluous because the cursor for a `div` is *only* visible when the mouse is over it. There is no reason to remove it once the user hovers out because the cursor wouldn't be seen at that time anyway.

Comment: While the question was asked very narrowly (about DIVs) this answer applies broadly.  It is useful for any HTML element such as tables, <p>'s, buttons, etc.  That's why I +1'd it.

Answer (score 12):

You actually don't need jQuery, just CSS. For example, here's some HTML:

```
<div class="special"></div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.special
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This will

```
#myDiv
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, JQuery can be safely replaced with vanilla JS. Here's how you would change the style of the `div`. Let's assume that `div` has `id="myDiv"`, then:

```js
const myDivElem = document.querySelector("#myDiv");
myDiv.style.cursor = "pointer";
```

where the argument of `querySelector` can be any CSS selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think `:hover` was missing in above answers. So following would do the needful.(if css was required)

```
#myDiv:hover
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Worked for me without the :hover, and presumably many more as the answer has a lot of positive votes. Did you try it?