# Show a "Finger" on <li> hover like its an <a>

Tags: css, knockout.js, html-lists

i have a realy stupid problem -.-
following:

```
<ul id="selectable" data-bind="foreach: folders">
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-bind=" text: $data, click: $root.goToFolder"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

its [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) combined with a bit of [SammyJS](http://sammyjs.org)...
atm you see i got a 'a' inside of the 'li'... so that there will appear this "finger" on the mousehover... but if i remove the 'a', ofc the "finger" wont be shown. instead it will appear this (lets call it) text-editor cursor... but its not obviously to the user that he is able to klick this element... is there a way to show this "finger" like on a link hover?

in [this](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail) example they have also

```
<ul><li>Item</li></ul>
```

and it shows this "finger"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the mouse cursor on mouser over to anchor-like style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185044/change-the-mouse-cursor-on-mouser-over-to-anchor-like-style)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

References:

- [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

Answer (score 2):

Add `cursor: pointer` to `li`.

```
li {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

check [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/cursor/) for information.

Comment: Check w3fools.com 

I suggest the MDN

Comment: @ Sprottenwels any reason?

Comment: Also: it's [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/), *not* 'W3CSchools'. Not that the implied connection to the W3 is any more justified with the omission of the 'C'.

Comment: @user1671639 "Bad education hurts.". Check the "reasons" section

Comment: @DavidThomas Sorry.  I've changed it.  Thanks for pointing the mistake.

Comment: @Sprottenwels Oh.  So I will avoid w3schools for reference.

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Actually, that pseudo selector is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Following CSS will take care of this:

```
li { cursor: hand; cursor: pointer; }
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that 'hand' is not a valid property
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor

Even if it was, it would be overridden by the second one, therefore, this makes no sense

Comment: IE 5.0 and 5.5 only supported hand. Since IE 6 and 7 support pointer, it is not necessary to use hand but it is nice to have cross browser support.